# Extracting vector graphics from pdf with Inkscape

Tags: pdf, graphics, inkscape

I'd like to extract some pdf images from a paper for presentation purposes. In windows, Adobe Illustrator works just fine, but I now have to perform this task in a Debian box.

Two popular solutions I found online are using

- [pdfimage](http://stefaanlippens.net/extract-images-from-pdf-documents)
- [Inkscape](https://superuser.com/questions/302045/how-to-extract-vector-from-pdf-file)

The pdfimage does not meet my needs since I want vector graphics (pdf) rather than jpgs so I prefer to use Inkscape, but it does not work as expected. I hope I could use some selector tool to drag a box and select everything inside as I normally did with Illustrator, but none of the tools in Inkscape works.

If I use the "select and transform objects" tool (the black arrow), the whole pdf page is selected while I only want a small portion; if I use the "edit path by nodes" tool (the black triangle arrow with some nodes) I can only select a single object at a time. Drag and drop (even with the shift key pressed) does not work.

I'm wondering if there's a way to get around this, or is there a better tool in Debian to achieve the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my humble opinion, I can suggest the way I use to get **vector** images from pdf

there is a tool called

**pdftocairo**, contained into **poppler-utils**

- http://poppler.freedesktop.org/

syntax:

```
pdftocairo [options] <PDF-file> [<output-file>]
```

pdftocairo is able to produce, in output, both raster and vector format, between these last, it is able to convert the content of **single pdf page** (if you have a **multipage** pdf doc, you first need to **explode** this in its single pdf pages, with **pdftk** for instance), into:

> - -ps                    : generate PostScript file
> - -eps                   : generate Encapsulated PostScript (EPS)
> - -svg                   : generate a Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) file

the best output format for your needs may be the **svg**, so after converted the pdf page you can open this svg with any svg app (with **inkscape** or  the good old **sodipodi** for instance), select the vector elements you want extract and save

RESUMING:

if you have a **MULTIPAGE PDF**

1. you FIRST split this multipage pdf into its single pages (create a
   folder for this single pages)

   ```
   pdftk file.pdf burst
   ```
2. then use **pdftocairo** to convert any pdf page into **svg**

   ```
   for f in *.pdf; do pdftocairo -svg $f; done
   ```

Comment: It doesn't work. After I convert it into svg, Inkscape still cannot select the object I want

Comment: you needed probably to **ungroup** the elements before to be able to select the single item

Answer (score 13):

You can split multi-page pdf files using pdftk, then using inkscape to convert pdf to svg file using command line, e.g

```
inkscape --without-gui --file=input.pdf --export-plain-svg=output.svg
```

Comment: Does it allow batch extraction of vector graphics?

Comment: Great, it worked! Splitting done with http://www.splitpdf.com then ran suggested command